# Calculate the Arc length of a Polar curve $r=1+\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: calculus

> Given the polar equation, $r=1+\cos(2\theta)$,  prove that the length of the curve corresponding to $0 \leq\theta \leq2\pi$ is $8+\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\log(2+\sqrt{3})$.

Applying integration to find arc length, $l$,  in polar form:
$\int_\alpha^\beta\sqrt{r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2}d\theta$

$r^2=(1+\cos(2\theta))^2=1+2\cos(2\theta)+\cos^2(2\theta)$,

and, $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-2\sin(2\theta)\Rightarrow (\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2=4\sin^2(2\theta)=4-4\cos^2(2\theta)$

$\therefore r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2=5+2\cos(2\theta)-3\cos^2(2\theta)$

Completing the square, $5+2\cos(2\theta)-3\cos^2(2\theta)=3\left[\frac{16}{9}-(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})^2 \right]$

Just doing the integration using (1), but without limits to get a function only, I get:

$\int\sqrt{r^2+(\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2}d\theta=\int\sqrt{3\left[\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2-(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})^2 \right]}d\theta=\sqrt{3}\int\sqrt{\left[\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2-(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})^2 \right]}d\theta$

The integral has the general form: $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx=\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\arcsin\frac{x}{a}$

Ignoring factor of $\sqrt{3}$ the integral is:

$\int\sqrt{\left[\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2-(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})^2 \right]}d\theta=\frac{((\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})\sqrt{(\frac{4}{3})^2-(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})^2}}{2}+ \frac{\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}{2}\arcsin\frac{(\cos(2\theta)-\frac{1}{3})}{\frac{4}{3}}$

No log term in the numerical solution.

Another idea I had was to try using $\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}=\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(t)}}$, but this leads to a substitution which doesn't give the log term?

I'm a bit stuck with this one. Most of the other examples I've read, e.g. for $r=1+\cos(\theta)$ seem to be OK. It's the $\cos(2\theta)$ causing the problem for me.

Comment: That's not correct. The integral is not in the form $ \displaystyle \int\sqrt{a^2-x^2} ~dx$, but in the form $ \displaystyle \int\sqrt{a^2- (f(x))^2} ~dx$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am still none the wiser!

Answer (score 1):

$r = 1 + \cos2\theta = 2 \cos^2\theta$

$r_{\theta} = - 4 \cos\theta \sin\theta$

$ \displaystyle l = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{4\cos^4\theta + 16 \cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta} ~ d\theta$

$ \displaystyle l = 8 \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos\theta \sqrt{1 + 3 \sin^2\theta} ~ d\theta$

Now substitute $t = \sin\theta$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh crumbs! I missed the obvious double angle identity, although I have been using this, but making the problem even more complicated! I'll give it a go from there, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: I got a 4sin^2 term, how did you get 3sin^2?

Comment: once you take out $2 \cos\theta$, inside the square root, you are left with $\cos^2\theta + 4 \sin^2\theta = 1 + 3 \sin^2\theta$

Comment: I took out  4cos^2

Comment: yes which is $2 \cos\theta$ outside of square root

Comment: But then did the fatal mistake of not leaving a cos^2 term inside the sqrt for the cos^4 term! Stupid me!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!